# Change the H3 text color depends on value from database using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

So, this is the line from the code.

PHP:

```
<div class="col">
    <h3 class="text-start name" style="font-size: 12px;color: var(--bs-secondary);" id="bizApproval"><?php echo $bizApproval ;?></h3>
</div>
```

which `<?php echo $bizApproval ;?>` this will get the value from database which either `Pending, Approved, Banned` but what I want is if its `Pending` the text color `yellow`, if `Approved` text color `green` and if `Banned` text color `red`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need JavaScript for this. You can create in your css file some color classes like this (this is a example):

```
.pending-color{
    color: yellow;
}
.banned-color{
    color: red;
}
.approved-color{
    color: green;
}
```

And in your php use this:

NOTE: assuming your `<?php echo $bizApproval ;?>` have the `Pending`, `Approved`, `Banned` values.

```
<div class="col">
    <h3 class="text-start name <?php echo $bizApproval.'-color'; ?>" style="font-size: 12px; id="bizApproval"> <?php echo $bizApproval ;?></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all it is not said that the server accepts the short code and according to the word it is "Pending" not "pending" so you have to adapt the writing :)

Comment: But this one doesn't work. I don't know why

Comment: Btw, thankss guys for your answer. I'm very appreciated. I've searched everywhere. I hope this will help anyone out there. Peace :D

Comment: @SimoneRossaini yes, changed.

Comment: @Adamakmartry it now

Answer (score 1):

You can simple create a variable with color and put into class like:

```
<?php

$color = ($bizApproval === 'Pending') ? 'yellow' : (($bizApproval === 'Approved') ? 'green' : 'red');
?>
<div class="col">
    <h3 class="text-start name" style="font-size: 12px;color: <?php echo color; ?>;" id="bizApproval"><?php echo $bizApproval ;?></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Can u do it with javascript?

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of complicating life, if the data comes in `PHP` not from an `Ajax` call why should you use `Javascript`?

Comment: Haha because this is the first time I saw. I never knew php can change the text color

Comment: :) yep, simple output a color directly into style or class